# display message after clicking asp.net button control

Tags: asp.net-ajax

After clicking asp.net button, in the button click event I have 5 modules getting executed in succession;

```
Protected Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
       Module1()
       Module2()
       Module3()
       Module4()
       Module5()
End Sub
```

Now I want to display the user, a label message showing the current module that is getting executed. something like "processing module 1...."

Note: Each of the modules do some heavy data processing work in the server that consumes lot of time depending on the volume.   Can anyone help with some sample code ? I'm ok with ajax update panel.